# How to find out if my number has 4 decimal places

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out if my number has 4 decimal places and if it's more then that it needs to throw out an error. The problem I'm having is that I'm struggling to check for the 4 decimal places

I have this

```
$rem = $num - (int)$num;
```

and then doing `strlen((string)$rem)` but when I `dd($rem)` I get other numbers attached to it.

For example

I have `45939.1541444444` but when I `dd()` I get `0.15414444440103`
It's the same if I only have a number with 4 decimal places there is other numbers attached

Comment: i'd do something like this. [Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by `.`, take the decimals and count how many chars in the string. Simply and reliable

Comment: If you used the accepted answer from the duplicate for this, you would have to change the number of digits it matches using `'/\.\d{5,}/'`

Comment: Sorry, your question not so clear. Do you want to know how many digits have the number after decimal  point?

Comment: @LelioFaieta that was it. I was over thinking it and didn't think of using explode. Thank you so much